# Multipart post with Alamofire and swiftyjson

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using alamofire for my signup form. I have one profile picture and some others fields like email, username, password, password_confirmation.
Data must be posted in raw json form.

```
        let signupBag = [
            "member_profile": [
                "photo": "URL",
                "user_attributes": [
                    "email": "\(txtEmail.text)",
                    "username": "\(txtName.text)",
                    "password": "\(txtPassword.text)",
                    "password_confirmation": "\(txtConfirmPwd.text)"
                ]
            ]
        ]
        NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.startAnimating(activityData)
        HelperClass(). doPostMultiPartFormRequest(url: BASE_URL+SIGNUP , param: signupBag, completion: { (dataResponse,swiftJSON,error) in
            guard error == nil else
            {
                NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.stopAnimating()
                HelperClass.showAlertViewWithTitle(title: "Error", Text: "\(error!.localizedDescription)", controllerToShowOn: self)

                return
            }
            print(swiftJSON!)

            if swiftJSON!["errors"].stringValue != ""
            {
                NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.stopAnimating()
                HelperClass.showAlertViewWithTitle(title: swiftJSON!["message"].stringValue, Text: swiftJSON!["errors"].stringValue, controllerToShowOn: self)
            }else{

                NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.stopAnimating()
             self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showProfile", sender: self)
            }

             NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.stopAnimating()


        })
```

Helperclass method

```
func doPostMultiPartFormRequest(url:String,  param:[String:Any], completion:@escaping (JSON?,Error?) -> Void)
    {
        print("Method indicator")
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (formData) in
            //setting normal params
            for (key, value) in param {
                if value is String
                {
                    formData.append((value as! String).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
            }

            //setting data params
            for (key, value) in param {
                if value is UIImage
                {
                    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(value as! UIImage,0.3)!
                    formData.append(imageData, withName: key, fileName: "myImage.png", mimeType: "image/png")

                }
            }

        }, to: url, encodingCompletion:
            {
                (encodingResult) -> Void in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON{ response in
                        guard response.result.error == nil else {
                            print(upload.progress)
                            completion(nil, response.result.error)
                            return
                        }

                        if let value = response.result.value
                        {
                            completion(JSON(value),nil)
                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(nil, error)
                    break
                }
        }


        )
    }
```

But I am getting "unable to connect to server". I am using alamofire along with swiftyJson.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `BASE_URL+SIGNUP `? The error is telling you that the server can't be found at the locator you're providing, so the first step is to confirm the locator.

Comment: Yes I have checked that via POSTMAN. Just multipartUpload isn't working

Comment: Hmm - not sure what to say then. Sometimes you'll get more information beyond "unable to connect to server", so breakpointing at the error and introspecting what the iOS client sees, and comparing that to the server logs at the same time would be my only other suggestion. Good luck!